# Fontawesome webfont show square on content property ( work fine on local and stuck on prod environnement )

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome, inspector

I'am using fontAwesome 4.7 in an Angular 6 project so I use the path of fontAwesome.css on my angular.json from "node_module" folder.

My issue is icons using css properties not works on prod envireonnement but on local works fine & ( icons using css classes on HTML elements works fine in both local and prod envireonnement ).

When I inspect element on my local I see that icons using css propoerties shown like that

```
.panel-control-collapse:before {
content: "";
}
```

and in my css file its like that :

```
.panel-control-collapse:before {
content: "\f068";
}
```

but for icons using css on html like that :

```
<a class="fa fa-upload" title="Importer en masse"></a>
```

works fine

so my issue that I'm forced to use icons from css properties but it stucks with that square :(

Comment: Is the font uploaded to the server?

Comment: Are you using sass?

Comment: Paulie_D Yes.
MiomirDancevic Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reslove the issue but I didn't understand from where it comes ( I think the problem was with my ***scss*** file ) so what I have done is :

I remove this part of ***css*** from my ***style.scss*** file.

```
.panel-control-collapse:before { font-family: FontAwesome; content: "\f068"; }
```

And I put it in a new ***css*** file created in the same root of my ***style.scss*** file.

**And then it works**

Answer (score -1):

**angular.json**

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/",
                "output": "./assets/fonts/"
              }
            ]
```

**styles.scss**

```
$fa-font-path: "/assets/fonts/";
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. I have reslove the issue but I didn't understand from where it comes ( I think the problem was with my SCSS file ) so what I have done is : 

I remove this part of css from my style.scss file.

`.panel-control-collapse:before {
font-family: FontAwesome;
content: "\f068";
}`

and I put it in a new CSS file created in the same root of my style.scss file.
and then it works